# Excel file making hidden instance visible

Tags: excel, vb.net

In my VB.Net Excel VSTO add-in, I open a bunch of excel files in the background to retrieve information from. The user should not see this, nor interact with this.

This is done by creating a new instance of Excel, and loading the files with the following code:

```
Dim loadExcelInstance as Excel.Application = New Excel.Application()
loadExcelInstance.Visible = False
loadExcelInstance.Workbooks.Open("Path\To\File", False, True)
```

This last part is to make sure the files are opened as read only. All files are marked as `Shared` from within Excel.

What happens, is that the files get read in the background, as they should be, untill this happens:

When one particular file gets loaded, the `loadExcelInstance.Visible` property suddenly changes to `True`, and this workbook, along with all the other workbooks opened after it become visible.

In this visible window, the workbook itself is displayed, but the ribbon, which is normally visible in Excel is not.

Yesterday, this happend with one workbook. After copying all data from this workbook to a new one, saved under the same name and deleting the old one, behavior was back to normal.

Today, this happens with two workbooks.

Does anyone know why this happens, and how I can prevent it?

Edit: To show in seperate test code what happens:

```
    Dim goodTestInstance = New Excel.Application()
    goodTestInstance.Visible = False
    goodTestInstance.AutomationSecurity = Microsoft.Office.Core.MsoAutomationSecurity.msoAutomationSecurityForceDisable
    Dim badTestInstance = New Excel.Application()
    badTestInstance.Visible = False
    badTestInstance.AutomationSecurity = Microsoft.Office.Core.MsoAutomationSecurity.msoAutomationSecurityForceDisable

    goodTestInstance.Workbooks.Open("Path\To\GoodFile.xlsm", False, True)
    badTestInstance.Workbooks.Open("Path\To\BadFile.xlsm", False, True)
```

When the code reaches the opening of the good file, it is opened in the background as it is supposed to be. When the code reaches the opening of the bad file, it is opened visible, but without the ribbon.

Comment: Is the particular file with event `Private Sub Workbook_Open()` on it?

Comment: @Vityata: In the excel-vba viewer under `VBAProject (workbookName.xlsm)` there are no functions, it says `Project is unviewable`. Is this what you meant?

Comment: Does your use of the files require that their macros are enabled? If not, set `loadExcelInstance.AutomationSecurity=Microsoft.Office.Core.M‌​soAutomationSecurity‌​.msoAutomationSecuri‌​tyForceDisable`

Comment: @TnTinMn: Sorry for the late reply... I tried your suggestion, but the instance still becomes visible...

Comment: If disabling any macro execution by the workbooks does not solve the issue, then the only possible culprits I can think of are your code or possibly some other add-in.  If you limit your code to just opening the offending workbook by itself, does it become visible?  Possibly write a separate test routine for this.

Comment: @TnTinMn: Sorry for the late reply... I edited my question to show the test code... But truth be told, I kind of gave op hope and accepted that somehow these files can become corrupt...

Answer (score 0):

Thats more like a comment, but it is with a pic. Anyhow, can you check whether you have something like this in that file:

[image]

Comment: This does not seem to be the case. The only place where a `Private Sub Workbook_Open()` is present, is in the VBA code of an add-in which gets loaded, but this is also present in the files which don't set visibility to `True`

Comment: @DrDonut And if you completely ignore this file, then it works ok? For all the others?

Comment: Yes, if I take the 'bad' file out of the list of files to be loaded, the rest works without a problem...

Comment: Is the `bad` file with the same extension as the others? `xlsx`, `xlsb`?

Comment: Yes, all files have .xlsm extension.

Comment: @DrDonut Can you change the `bad` file to `xlsx` and see what is happening?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/137760/discussion-between-drdonut-and-vityata).